# Redirect URL's with bad file extensions

Tags: .net, .htaccess, redirect, iis

I'm running windows servers with IIS and normally I would do a redirect by simply adding a rule to .htaccess to redirect a couple of urls that have gotten into google index due a typo, however because its not a valid file type .net jumps in first and throws an application error.
The url in question ends: "/presents-for-her..." which includes the 3 dots, which is where I'm having the issue - anyone got any thoughts on how I can either get past the .net application(which we are not using) so I can .htaccess it  or to handle it within .net? There are only 4 bad urls so it wont take an extensive set of rules to sort out.

Comment: IIS does not support `.htaccess` file, so you should study IIS instead, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: I already have ISAPI rewrite installed and working but I will look at web.config redirect rules

Comment: "ISAPI rewrite", what ISAPI rewrite? Please choose the right terms to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still using IIS 5/6 in windows server 2003 or 2005? If you are using windows server 2008 or higher version. Then you shouldn't use ISAPI rewrite further.

Please use URL rewrite module instead.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

And it support to convert .htaccess to IIS rule.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules